# Convert date format in xslt from YYYYMMDD to MM/DD/YYYY

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am Having date in xml file in format like

> YYYYMMDD

Applying the xslt transformation i want to change the format to

> MM/DD/YYYY

.

For example,
Incoming format - 20160513
Output format - 05/13/2016

Comment: Please select either XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0, not both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given:

```
<date>20160513</date>
```

the following:

```
<xsl:template match="date">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 5, 2)"/>
        <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 7, 2)"/>
        <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 1, 4)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

will return:

```
<date>05/13/2016</date>
```

Answer (score 3):

XSLT 2.0 option...

```
<xsl:template match="date[matches(normalize-space(),'^\d{8}$')]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="replace(normalize-space(),
      '(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})',
      '$2/$3/$1')"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```